# How to intercept Spring Cloud Function messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream

I'm migrating from Spring Cloud Streams and the deprecated StreamListeners to Spring Cloud Function with its Consumers. I had in my applications an Interceptor to configure some log metadata and User context (thread local information) for my input messages. That was done with this kind of interceptor: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37466442/5230740.

Now, in Spring Cloud Function, the interceptor is no longer working. I found on the internet the feature called `org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.FunctionAroundWrapper` and it works, but I didn't find good documentation about it in the Spring pages. So, I don`t know if I can rely on this feature or I should use another approach?